# Dreams more "real" than "real" life

Tags: dreams

I have noticed last few months that my dreams are very real. This I say because if I recall a memory from some dream that I remember, that memory is usually more clear and stronger than most everyday life memories. I remember that better, coz I seem to be more "alive" in the dream.
If right now I think about dreaming from yesterday night, I **know** that during the dream I was more alive then I am right now.

I know this might be related to lucid dreaming, but I am not lucid dreamer - I haven't had a lucid dream ever.

What do you think could be going on here? Have you been in a similar situation?

Comment: I have to ask -- I can see this might be a topic of conversation with a friend, but in what way is it a question about Buddhist doctrine or practice?

Comment: I agree. This question has nothing to do with Buddhism.

Comment: @ChrisW With all due respect, I fail to understand how is this not buddhism related when buddhism cheifly relates to mind and mental phenomena. Awareness, nature of reality etc. are among the centralmost aspects of buddhism when practiced correctly; thus this question should belong here. also who is better to answer this than buddhists who are supposed to have deepest understanding in the world of awareness related phenomena.

Comment: In theory, "good" answers may be "backed up" by references/citations, or by personal experience. But not every question about personal experience is on-topic -- for example a question like, "Have you ever been frightened by an animal?" -- even though you could say this is a topic mentioned in the suttas and therefore ought to be on-topic. It's not that dreaming isn't mind-related, it's that the question isn't asking anything except like "What do you think?" and "Have you experienced this?"

Comment: Perhaps I might have "been in a similar situation" but even if I have, I'm not sure my answer would be on-topic -- because the topic of this site is "Buddhism" and not my subjective experience of dreaming -- and so I "blame" the question or question it, rather, I don't see what it's asking that's explicitly related to Buddhism. Someone else might be able to answer it as-is (so I didn't close it), but apparently other people too agreed (by upvoting my comment) that they're not sure how it is, currently, a question about Buddhist doctrine or practice.

Answer (score 1):

I've had meditation visions and lucid dreams that were more vivid, sharp, and clear than normal human experience where I wear glasses.

In those visions, I don't need glasses and have better than perfect vision.

This kind of thing you're talking about, hyper realisim more "real" than human life which seems like a dream in comparison, is also commonly reported from people who've had near death experiences where their mind separated from the body.

The fact that you retain memory from you dreams clearly doesn't seem normal though.
Unless you're reviewing those memories right after you wake up and copying the data from your mental body memory into your human brain.

If you frame your question differently, in terms of the khandhas of perception and  volition as agents of memory, between mental body and waking life body, then I think that would address the supposed non Buddhist elements.

Comment: Thank you for your insightful answer. I am not sure about the Khandhas etc as I am not super well read in formal literature. I, however, have had an extremely deep experience on LSD when I became awake and the everyday life became dream like. I also saw infinite ocean of consciousness etc in that state, and saw that I will never die or I was never born. That thing lasted months..but I still have remnant effects. I am saying this because you mentioned near death experiences, and for me it was quite that.

Comment: Also, to clarify, I don't really retain all the memories. It is just one or two glimpses out of a few dreams but they are quite real and vivid when i recall them. More than my own key real life memories from the past. 

Could you please elaborate or refer me to some resources related to what you said in your answer?

Comment: if you search for 'near death experience' on youtube, you'll find tons of interviews with people https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=near+death+experience